# Using ILMerge with NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, ilmerge

We have a core.dll which is a separate solution, this is in subversion. Whenever we update to the svn, bamboo creates a nupkg for us. The problem is that in the projects that we use the core, every time nuget updates the package to a new version number, the True dissapears in the csproj file. Any way around this?

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Core.Utilities, Version=1.3.0.50, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Core.1.3.0.50\lib\Core.Utilities.dll</HintPath>
  <ILMerge>True</ILMerge>
</Reference>
```

When we would update to version 51 through nuget the ILMerge tag will disappear.

Another problem is the .proj file where the version number isn't updated at all.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet relies on the the underlying VS layer to add references while installing a package.
In this case a work around would be to re-add the ILMerge using the install.ps1 script of the package ( install.ps1 exposes the dte object using which you can access the project object and its references ...)